# confusion about momentum setting in CNTK

Tags: python, cntk

I'm super confused exactly how momentum work in cntk
From the docs i see there is two ways
1. the momentum as time constant

> #Use a fixed momentum of 1100 for all samples 
>    m = momentum_as_time_constant_schedule(1100)

Where i set the momentum value ?
what will be the value of this fixed momentum ?

2. the 'normal way' i.e: the one I understand

> C.adam(parameters=res.parameters, lr=0.4, momentum=**0.9**, variance_momentum=0.9, minibatch_size=32)

I see we can setup directly the parameter but somehow there is also

> momentum = **momentum_schedule(0.9)**

and to be even more confusing for me i see this kind of thing in the unit test of CNTK

> C.momentum_sgd(parameters=res.parameters, lr=[0.4, 0.1, 0.001], momentum=**[0.9]**,
>                                   minibatch_size=32, epoch_size=512)

yet another way to pass momentum but with a single list

Can someone please help me understand this ?

Answer (score 4):

In general, please see our manual on [how to use learners](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Manual/Manual_How_to_use_learners.ipynb) for detailed explanation. Copied the part related to your questions below:

1. `momentum_as_time_constant_schedule` is a legacy API, the relationship between a time constant and the momentum decay factor is

   - `momentum = exp(-minibatch_size / time_constant)`
   - `time_constant = minibatch_size / log (1 / momentum)`

Please see the manual for detailed explanation and its origin. Also see the wiki page on time constant: [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant).

2. C.adam(parameters=res.parameters, lr=0.4, momentum=0.9, variance_momentum=0.9, minibatch_size=32) is a convenient way of saying:

   ```
   lr = C.learning_parameter_schedule(0.4, minibatch_size = 32)

   momentum = C.momentum_schedule(0.9, minibatch_size = 32)

   var_momentum = C.momentum_schedule(0.9, minibatch_size = 32)

   C.adam(prameters=res.parameters, lr = lr, momentum = momentum, var_momentum = var_momentum, minibatch_size = 32)
   ```
3. `C.momentum_sgd(parameters=res.parameters, lr=[0.4, 0.1, 0.001], momentum=[0.9], minibatch_size=32, epoch_size=512)` is convenient way of saying:

   ```
   lr = C.learning_parameter_schedule([0.4, 0.1, 0.001], minibatch_size = 32, , epoch_size=512)

   momentum = C.momentum_schedule([0.9], minibatch_size = 32, epoch_size=512)

   C.momentum_sgd(parameters=res.parameters, lr = lr, momentum = momentum, minibatch_size = 32, epoch_size=512)
   ```

The meaning of having a list of rates instead of a single number is that it is a learning rate (momentum) schedule instead of a single learning rate (or momentum):  Different learning rates (momentums, var momentums) will be applied to different samples:

- In the example, `0.4` will applied to the first 512 samples; `0.1` will be applied from 513th sample to the 1024th sample; `0.001` will be applied from 1025th sample to 1536th sample.
- In general,  with a list `[p_1, p_2, .., p_n]`, the i-th parameter `p_i` in the list is used as the value from the `(epoch_size * (i-1) + 1)`-th sample to the (epoch_size * i)-th sample. If list contains pair, i.e. `[(num_epoch_1, p_1), (num_epoch_n, p_2), .., (num_epoch_n, p_n)]`, the i-th parameter is used as a value from the `(epoch_size * (num_epoch_0 + ... + num_epoch_2 + ... + num_epoch_(i-1) + 1)`-th sample to the `(epoch_size * num_epoch_i)`-th sample (taking `num_epoch_0 = 0` as a special initialization).

See [learning_parameter_schedule](https://%20cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.learners.html?highlight=learning_parameter_schedule#cntk.learners.learning_parameter_schedule) for detailed explanation.